# I have someone who has a green card and holds a Vietnamese passport and wants to travel to Israel for a pilgrimage

Tags: visas, israel, us-residents, vietnamese-citizens

I have clients who hold green cards in the US and need to get a visa to go to Israel on a pilgrimage, what do they need to do

Comment: They need to apply for the visa at the appropriate Israeli consulate.  A list may be found at http://www.israelemb.org/washington/AboutTheEmbassy/Pages/US-Missions.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Green card is not a travel document. You can't use it to for travel.

Vietnamese citizens/passport holders are [required](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Documents/VisaRequirements-Tourists.pdf) to obtain B/2 Visitor visa, [here is the link of how to do it](http://www.israelemb.org/washington/ConsularServices/Pages/Visa-Information.aspx).